# IHierarchyData and IHierarchicalEnumerable in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, hierarchical-data

Currently,I know how to do a lazy implementation of the loading procedure of the nodes in a treeview control, and read the related questions in stackoverflow, but I'm also reading about IHierarchyData  and IHierarchicalEnumerable interfaces in asp.net (I didn't know to code asp.net) that allow to bind a collection to a treeview in order to display the items automatically.

It would like to know if I can do the same in winforms and C#. I think that the interfaces previous mentioned are not available in winforms.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Forms `TreeView` does not know how to bind to an `IHierarchyData` instance, which isn't surprising given that the `IHierarchyData` and related interfaces are intended for consumption by web controls (especially site maps).

However, it's really not too hard to build your own data binding class.  This seemed like an interesting problem so I threw one together just for fun.  I'll walk you through the inner workings.

First, create a basic Component class.  Visual Studio will start you off with code like this:

```
public partial class TreeViewHierarchyBinding : Component
{
    public TreeViewHierarchyBinding()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public TreeViewHierarchyBinding(IContainer container)
    {
        container.Add(this);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

One obvious piece of "state" this component needs to have is a mapping from each `TreeNode` to its `IHierarchyData`.  Now we can hack around this by throwing it in the `TreeNode`'s `Tag` property, but let's aim to make this component as non-invasive as possible and keep track of its own state.  Hence, we'll use a dictionary.  Add this field to the class:

```
private Dictionary<TreeNode, IHierarchyData> nodeDictionary = new 
    Dictionary<TreeNode, IHierarchyData>();
```

Now, at a minimum, this component needs to know how to populate a specific parent `TreeNode` of a `TreeView` class from its correspondingly bound `IHierarchyData`, so let's write that code next:

```
private void PopulateChildNodes(TreeNodeCollection parentCollection,
    IHierarchicalEnumerable children)
{
    parentCollection.Clear();
    foreach (object child in children)
    {
        IHierarchyData childData = children.GetHierarchyData(child);
        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(childData.ToString());
        if (childData.HasChildren)
        {
            childNode.Nodes.Add("Dummy");   // Make expandable
        }
        nodeDictionary.Add(childNode, childData);
        parentCollection.Add(childNode);
    }
}

private void UpdateRootNodes(TreeView tv, IHierarchyData hierarchyData)
{
    if (tv == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    tv.Nodes.Clear();
    if (hierarchyData != null)
    {
        IHierarchicalEnumerable roots = hierarchyData.GetChildren();
        PopulateChildNodes(tv.Nodes, roots);
    }
}
```

This part should be pretty straightforward.  The first method just populates a `TreeNodeCollection` (i.e. the `Nodes` property of a `TreeNode`) with the hierarchy obtained from an `IHierarchyData` instance, using the `IHierarchyEnumerable` interface.  The only really interesting things this method does are:

1. Adding a dummy node when the `IHierarchyData` instance has children; this makes the "+" visible in the tree view, otherwise we wouldn't be able to expand any deeper; and
2. Adding the newly-added node to the dictionary with the `IHierarchyData` instance it matches with.

The second method is even simpler, it does the initial "binding work", replacing whatever is in the **root** of the tree with our top-level `IHierarchyData` instance.

The next thing our component needs to be able to do is hook the loading events from the `TreeView` to perform lazy-loading.  Here's the code to do that:

```
private void RegisterEvents(TreeView tv)
{
    tv.BeforeExpand += TreeViewBeforeExpand;
}

private void UnregisterEvents(TreeView tv)
{
    tv.BeforeExpand -= TreeViewBeforeExpand;
}

private void TreeViewBeforeExpand(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Checked)
    {
        return;
    }
    IHierarchyData hierarchyData;
    if (nodeDictionary.TryGetValue(e.Node, out hierarchyData))
    {
        PopulateChildNodes(e.Node.Nodes, hierarchyData.GetChildren());
        e.Node.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

First two methods should be self-explanatory, and the third method is the actual lazy-loading code.  We're cheating a little here, using the `TreeNode.Checked` property to delineate whether or not the child nodes have already been loaded so we don't do any unnecessary reloads.  I always do this when I implement lazy-loaded trees because, in my experience, I almost never use the `TreeNode.Checked` property.  However, if you do need to use this property for something else, you can either use a different property (like `Tag`), create another dictionary to hold the expanded states, or modify the existing dictionary to hold a composite class (containing the `IHierarchyData` as well as an `Expanded` property).  I'm keeping it simple for now.

The rest should already make sense to you if you've implemented lazy-loading in a tree before, so let's skip ahead.  Really the only thing left to do at this point is implement some designer/user properties that will actually wire up the tree and data:

```
private IHierarchyData dataSource;
private TreeView treeView;

[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public IHierarchyData DataSource
{
    get { return dataSource; }
    set
    {
        if (value != dataSource)
        {
            dataSource = value;
            nodeDictionary.Clear();
            UpdateRootNodes(treeView, value);
        }
    }
}

[Category("Behavior")]
[DefaultValue(null)]
[Description("Specifies the TreeView that the hierarchy should be bound to.")]
public TreeView TreeView
{
    get { return treeView; }
    set
    {
        if (value != treeView)
        {
            if (treeView != null)
            {
                UnregisterEvents(treeView);
            }
            treeView = value;
            nodeDictionary.Clear();
            RegisterEvents(value);
            UpdateRootNodes(treeView, dataSource);
        }
    }
}
```

Easy peasy.  We've got a `DataSource` property that accepts the root `IHierarchyData`, and a `TreeView` property which you'll be able to access from the designer.  Again, simple stuff here, when the `DataSource` property is updated, we just reset the lookup and repopulate the root.  When the `TreeView` property is updated we have to do a little more work, registering the events, making sure to unregister events from the old tree view, and doing all the same stuff we do when the data source changes.

That's really all there is to it!  Open up the Windows Forms designer, drop a `TreeView`, then drop a `TreeViewHierarchyBinding` and set its `TreeView` property to the tree view you just dropped.  Finally, in your code somewhere (i.e. in the `Form_Load` event), give it a data source:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
    treeViewHierarchyBinding1.DataSource = new FileSystemHierarchyData(dir);
}
```

(Note - this uses the example `FileSystemHierarchyData` that's on the [MSDN page for IHierarchyData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchydata.aspx).  The example isn't very robust, it doesn't check for `UnauthorizedAccessException` or anything, but it's good enough to demonstrate this).

And that's it.  Run your app and watch it bind.  You can now reuse the `TreeViewHierarchyBinding` component anywhere - just drop it on a form, assign it a `TreeView`, and give it an `IHierarchyData` instance as a data source.

I've put the [complete code on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/yDxJiHct) if you want a copy-and-paste version.

Have fun!

Comment: Instead of using the Checked property, you could also use a dummy child node name that is impossible or improbable (like having a \ in a file system tree). This way, the IsLoaded validation could be
If TreeNodeCollection.Nodes.Count == 1 and TreeNodeCollection.Nodes[0].Text == "\MyDummyValue/"

Answer (score 1):

The interfaces are available, but will require you to add a reference to System.Web.UI. (It might also require you to use the full .NET Framework redistributable rather than the Client Profile, although I'm not certain about that.)

The larger question is: Does the WinForms TreeView control automatically understand how to work with these interfaces? I believe the answer to that question is "No", but you would need to test/verify that.

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting article [here](http://www.scottcreynolds.com/archive/2008/08/15/binding-complex-types-to-winforms-treeview-with-extension-methods-and.aspx) that shows you how to build extension methods to achieve what I think you're looking for. There is no native availability within the System.Windows.Forms.TreeView to bind to a collection from what I can find.

You CAN include System.Web.UI in your project to make the IHierarchyData and IHierarchicalEnumerable interfaces available, but the TreeView will not be able to attach to them without the extension methods.

The sample source code from the web site will let you bind any IDictionary collection to the TreeView.